# OWASP Amass Subcommands

Tags: security, owasp

I do not know why Amass only show 2 commands. Amass Enum and Intel. Why? In the github there is more than 2 commands.

My second questions, what is FQDN, manage, and other Amass Enum results? Thank you so much for helping me out. I am so confuse right now.

Detailed and easy explanation for all my questions

Answer (score 0):

FQDN means domain name without any addition. Maps.google.com is FQDN is google.com.
Amass has ony 3 main commands. Those are intel , db and enum. Each main command have multiple sub commands. You can visit the github page from: https://github.com/owasp-amass/amass/blob/master/doc%2Fuser_guide.md
I wish it helps.

Comment: I did not find db subcommand too. İ Tried it yesterday. The latest version